# Привязать пользователя к другой модели Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

Пытаюсь выполнить простые действия по включению авторизовавшегося пользователя в экземпляр вторичной модели через внешний ключ "ManyToMany".

Модель:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Entry(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name='Заявку оформил')
```

Cоздаю экземпляр существующего пользователя из записи в БД:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> u
<User: doctor>
```

Теперь передаю этого пользователя в экземпляр Entry:

```
>>> entry = Entry(id=1, author=u)
```

Получаю исключение:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Z:\Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 568, in __init__
    _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "Z:\Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 537, in __set__
    manager.set(value)
  File "Z:\Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 983, in set
    objs = tuple(objs)
TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в модели `Entry` `author` имеет тип `ManyToManyField`, и при создании объекта ожидает итерируемый объект User'ов, поэтому правильной будет запись

```
entry = Entry(id=1, author=[u]) # !!!
entry.save()
```

Если для каждого `Entry` вы собираетесь подключать не более одного пользователя, нет смысла использовать `ManyToManyField`. Замените его на `ForeignKey` или `OneToOneField` (почитайте подробнее: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#s-module-django.db.models.fields.related)